# when gridview have lots of items ,"out of memory" issue

Tags: java, android, gridview, bitmap, out-of-memory

hi i have a gridview (It has two textboxes and one imageview)
The items are populated from db. I use a standard photo for items that haven't a photo. App works with 50 items but with 200 items it gives some error.

- logcat******  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError  at
  android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method) at
  android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:652)

  ---

ı try some methods that get from google suggest for loading large bitmap, but it didnt work. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

when I set inJustDecodeBounds true, app works but all items come empty..
here is my code get info from db:

```
private void refreshList(String sql)
{
    gridArray = new ArrayList<Stock>();
    final Cursor cursor = _SQLite.RawQueryTry(sql, null);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;

    if (cursor != null)
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
            {
                byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("FOTO"));
                Bitmap stockImage = null;
                ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = null;

                if (blob == null)
                {
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
                    stockImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.foto_yok, options);
                }
                else
                {
                    inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
                    stockImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);

                }
                String stockName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("STOK_ADI"));
                String stockNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("STOK_NO"));
                String stockCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("STOK_KODU"));
                String stockEntity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("BIRIM"));
                String stockKdvOranı = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("KDV_ORANI"));
                String stockRatio = TableUtils.getFieldValue("KATSAYI", "BIRIM", stockEntity, "STOKBIRI");
                String stockAmount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MIKTAR"));
                gridArray.add(new Stock(stockImage, stockName, stockNo, stockCode, stockKdvOranı, stockEntity, stockAmount, stockRatio, processNo));

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }

    gridAdapter = new AdapterStockGridView(this, R.layout.stockgriditems, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

}
```

and my adapter class :

```
public class AdapterStockGridView extends ArrayAdapter<Stock>
{
    Context context;
    int id;
    ArrayList<Stock> stock = new ArrayList<Stock>();

    public AdapterStockGridView(Context context, int id, ArrayList<Stock> stock)
    {
        super(context, id, stock);
        this.id = id;
        this.context = context;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(id, parent, false);

            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.stockCode = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.stockCode);
            holder.stockName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.stockName);
            holder.stockImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.stockImage);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Stock item = stock.get(position);
        holder.stockCode.setText(item.getStockCode());
        holder.stockName.setText(item.getStockName());
        holder.stockImage.setImageBitmap(item.getStockImage());

        return row;

    }

}

static class RecordHolder
{
    TextView stockName;
    TextView stockCode;
    ImageView stockImage;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're storing the blob as full size? If so, there's no need to do that as you're wasting too much space and you're having these memory issues. The users is not going to see the big image anyway, so redo your image storing in order to store the scaled down images as blobs.

You're getting these OOE because you're loading the full blob byte array - and the way it is now, you can't make use of the article from developer article.

Also, don't load the images in that `Stock` object as you're going to hold them unnecessarily. Rather than that, use a bitmap loader mechanism that keeps the images in a `LRUCache` and if not found in there, it loads them from database. In your `GridView` adapter `getView` method request to load that image. If found in `LRUCache`, get it from there, if not start an AsyncTask to get it from DB, add it in LRUCache and display it to the user.

Here is [a link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) with caching bitmaps with LRUCache.

Comment: my images max size 300KB, and 500x500 resulotion.. Stock class keeps all information of items.. And use them when necessary with position. I don't understand LRUCache using.. can u give an example about using of it in my code..

Comment: well, 500 x 500 resolution x 4 bytes per pixel means ~976 kb per image. That is the medium amount of space each image will take in memory. It's huge. How big does the image ends up showed to the user? Maybe 100 x 100 mostly. Each image would occupy ~39kb. See the difference? Updating the answer with a LRU cache article link.

Comment: I change images 200x200. it works :) but I can't understand exactly this issue. I have 200 items, if count is 500, will it work ?

Comment: No, it will not work ... You need to use a mechanism like LRUCache to make sure you load and use images as the app makes use of them. Once these are not used the application will dispose them. Also, keep the images to an optimized size (the best size is the size of the viewport).